# Difference in executing a command line in a different ways

Tags: mac, mojave, bash

Just so I understand the difference between executing the command line in Bash Terminal macOS Mojave.

Let's take for example the installation of a package named: stackexchange.pkg

What are the differences between the two command line below? Is the result the same? Pros and Cons?

```
/usr/sbin/installer -pkg path_to_stackexchange.pkg -target /

sh -c /usr/sbin/installer -pkg 'path_to_stackexchange.pkg' -target '/'
```

Comment: I do not think the second one (`sh -c /usr/sbin/installer -pkg 'path_to_stackexchange.pkg' -target '/'`) will work.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks. Any specific reasons?

Comment: I just ran the command and I get usage output for `/usr/bin/installer`. Maybe you meant `sh -c '/usr/sbin/installer -pkg path_to_stackexchange.pkg -target /'`. Or maybe `sh -c '$0 $@' /usr/sbin/installer -pkg 'path_to_stackexchange.pkg' -target '/'`

Comment: Assuming that you're trying to run a shell script in both cases, one of the big differences would be that the `sh script.sh` let's you run a script.sh that doesn't have execute permissions

Comment: @ernie: ....doesn't have execute permissions *in a new shell*. As opposed to `. script.sh` or `source script.sh` which executes in the same shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `sh` with its `-c` option, the argument after `-c` is taken as the command string to run. Thus, when you run

```
sh -c /usr/sbin/installer -pkg 'path_to_stackexchange.pkg' -target '/'
```

`sh` will run the command "`/usr/sbin/installer`". It will *not* pass on the rest of its arguments, because they're not part of the command string. If you want to include arguments, you'd need to do something like this:

```
sh -c "/usr/sbin/installer -pkg 'path_to_stackexchange.pkg' -target '/'"
```

The double-quotes make that a single long argument to `sh`, so it'll execute the whole thing and pass `-pkg` etc as arguments to the `installer` command.

(BTW, in the shell, quotes don't nest. Nesting quoted strings inside quoted strings -- like the single-quoted arguments inside that double-quoted argument -- isn't really a thing. In this case it does work, because the inside a double-quoted string, single-quotes are just regular characters. In more complicated situations, things can get weird and confusing.)

So what's happening to those other arguments after the command? Well, the command string (the argument after `-c`) functions a little like a miniature shell script, and those are passed to that mini-script as arguments. But they're not passed to the commands *in* that mini-script, unless the mini-script explicitly passes them on:

```
sh -c '/usr/sbin/installer "$@"' installer-thingie -pkg 'path_to_stackexchange.pkg' -target '/'
```

Here, inside the mini-script, the `"$@"` expands to the arguments to the mini-script (i.e. `-pkg`, `path_to_stackexchange.pkg`, etc.), thus passing them on to the `installer` command.

But what's that `installer-thingie` argument? That's the name the mini-script is run under, so it'll show up as `$0` inside the mini-script. Basically, it functions as a placeholder, and you could put pretty much anything there. "sh" is a common choice.

As for the pros and cons of using `sh -c` to run commands: unless there's some reason you really need to run another shell, just run the command directly. Running it with `sh -c` is more complicated and confusing, and (as you've experienced) easy to get wrong.

As @DavidAnderson pointed out, using `sh -c` is also less efficient, because it creates an additional shell process. If you look at the process tree for running `installer` directly (and assuming your interactive shell is zsh), it looks like this:

```
zsh───installer
```

But with `sh -c`, it's like this:

```
zsh───sh───installer
```

...it ran an `sh` process under your interactive shell, and then *that* ran `installer` as a subprocess.

On the other hand, if you prefer confusing complexity and inefficiency, there's no reason to stop at one unnecessary shell; why not add another `sh -c` to run the `sh -c` command?

```
sh -c "sh -c \"/usr/sbin/installer -pkg 'path_to_stackexchange.pkg' -target '/'\""
```

or even

```
sh -c "sh -c \"sh -c \\\"/usr/sbin/installer -pkg 'path_to_stackexchange.pkg' -target '/'\\\"\""
```

(did I mention that nesting quotes can get complicated?)

Comment: I would add that after correcting for the OP's syntax errors, the first command runs in the same shell and the second runs in a new shell.